# Different in "scope" and "context" in this Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'm using this basic event system in my Javascript code and I'm trying to document it for my coworkers.  I'm not really sure what the difference is in "scope" and "context" in this code.  Can anyone help me understand why I even need them both?

```
this.myClass.prototype.on = function (type, method, scope, context) {
    var listeners, handlers, scope;
    if ( !(listeners = this.listeners) ) {
        listeners = this.listeners = {};
    }

    if ( !(handlers = listeners[type]) ) {
        handlers = listeners[type] = [];
    }

    scope = (scope ? scope : window);
    handlers.push({
        method: method,
        scope: scope,
        context: (context ? context : scope)
    });
}

this.myClass.prototype.trigger = function(type, data, context) {
    var listeners, handlers, i, n, handler, scope;
    if (!(listeners = this.listeners)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(handlers = listeners[type])){
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0, n = handlers.length; i < n; i++){
        handler = handlers[i];
        if (context && context !== handler.context) continue;
        if (handler.method.call(
            handler.scope, this, type, data
        )===false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This code is unnecessarily confusing. The words `context` and `scope` are used to mean wrong things. First, let me explain what they should mean to every JavaScript developer:

A **context** of a function is the value of `this` for that function -- i.e. the object the function is called as a method of.

```
function F() { this.doSomething('good'); }
```

You can invoke this function in different contexts like this:

```
obj1 = { doSomething: function(x) { console.log(x); } }

obj2 = { doSomething: function(x) { alert(x); } }

F.call(obj1);
F.call(obj2);
```

There are many powerful programming patterns that emerge out of this. Function binding (Underscore `bind` or jQuery `proxy`) is one example.

**Scope** on the other hand defines the way JavaScript resolves a variable at run time. There are <strike>only two</strike> four scopes in JavaScript -- global, function, block, and module scopes. Moreover, it also deals with something called "scope chain" that makes closures possible.

---

Your `on` method saves the variable `scope` and then uses it in the `trigger` function as context, which is confusing (it shouldn't be named `scope` -- it's the context):

```
handler.method.call(
    handler.scope, this, type, data
)
```

And I have no idea what `this` is in the above call.

The `on` method also accepts a `context` which defaults to the supplied `scope` in case `context` is falsy. This `context` is then used to filter the functions to call in `trigger`.

```
context !== handler.context
```

This lets you group your handlers by associating them with an arbitrary object (which they have called `context`) and then invoke the entire group by just specifying the `context`.

Again, I think this code is overly convoluted and could have been written in a lot simpler way. But then, you shouldn't need to write your own event emitters like this in the first place -- every library has them ready for your use.

Comment: So basically, the scope was pointless like I thought.  I wish I could remember where I found this code.

Comment: Now there is block scope a well, for 'let' and 'const' in ES6. Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Technically speaking, isn't context in JS all of the variable references that apply in a given closure, rather than just a `this` binding?  I mean `vm.createContext` can take a bunch of variable bindings.

Comment: This answer, while good, is outdated. There are now four types of scope, not two. Global scope, module scope, block scope, and function scope.

Answer (score 13):

Scope pertains to the visibility of the variables, and context refers to the object within which a function is executed.

**Scope**:In JavaScript, scope is achieved through the use of functions. When you use the keyword “var” inside of a function, the variable that you are initializing is private, and cannot be seen outside of that function. But, if there are functions inside of this function, then those “inner” functions can “see” that variable; that variable is said to be “in-scope”. Functions can “see” variables that are declared inside of them. They can also “see” any that are declared outside of them, but never those declared inside of functions that are nested in that function. This is scope in JavaScript.

**Context**:It refers to the object within which a function is executed. When you use the JavaScript keyword “this”, that word refers to the object that the function is executing in.