# Why reducer does not respond to the action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

trying to make reducer works, but everytime "default" case fires.
Here is the code:

AC:

```
import {INPUT_IDEA_HANDLE} from "./types"

export function inputIdeaHandle(idea) {
  console.log('it is working, I have access to the idea');
  return {
    type: INPUT_IDEA_HANDLE,
    payload: idea
  }
}
```

Reducer :

```
import {INPUT_IDEA_HANDLE} from "../actions/types"

export default function (state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_IDEA_HANDLE :
      console.log('never fires');
      return action.payload;
    default:
      console.log('fires everytime');
      return state
  }
}

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import inputIdeaReducer from "./inputIdeaReducer.js"

export default combineReducers({
  inputIdea: inputIdeaReducer
});
```

**UPDATE**
I changed my trigger code, but keep getting

*Cannot read property 'props' of undefined*
in     *return this.props.inputHandle(value);*

Event trigger :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { inputIdeaHandle } from "../actions";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  changeHandle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = e.target.value;
    return this.props.inputHandle(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboard container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h4>Type your idea here</h4>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.changeHandle}
              value={this.props.inputIdea}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    inputIdea: state.inputIdea
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      inputHandle: inputIdeaHandle
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Triple checked everything, but still keep getting 'fires everytime' in console. Count on you, guys

Regards

Comment: You haven't shown how you triggered the state so we can detect the problem.

Comment: @AbundanceOshianor added

Comment: either you are hiding more code - like what `inputIdeaHandler` actually is (instead of it being the action exported in the first file) or you are doing something else somewhere in the code triggering a `dispatch`.  What you have here would do nothing - `inputIdeaHandler` just returns an object and then your `changeHandle` is done

Comment: @Deryck Yes, I fully added my code. Please, check it out

Comment: "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" you need to somehow bind your method when passing it as a callback. For example `onChange={this.changeHandle.bind(this)}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - Can't read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176248/react-js-cant-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with handling `this` context.

You can handle `this` context as follows

1. `constructor`

   `constructor() { 
     super(props); 
     this.changeHandle = this.changeHandle.bind(this)};
   }`
2. `Arrow function in render` : `onChange={e => this.changeHandle(e)}`
3. `React.createClass` : `React binds all functions to this.`
4. `Bind in render`:
   `onChange={this.changeHandle.bind(this)}`

Comment: I am using Redux, but error was in context. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

you have to import your actions from your action file
    import { postSelected } from '../containers/actions';

```
class Home extends Component {
  changeHandle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = e.target.value;
     return this.props.post(value);
  }

    <input type="text" onChange={this.changeHandle} />

} //end of class

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return{
    view: state.view
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return bindActionCreators({
     post: postSelected,
   },dispatch)
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

this should work edit it to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did as you said , but got error:  Cannot read property 'props' of undefined. on this call : this.props.inputHandle(value).