# Login fail with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'd like to activate Facebook login by react native firebase. My purpose is to move to Signin screen to Main Screen.

I use,

react-native: 0.52.2
react-native-firebase: ^3.2.4
react-navigation: ^1.0.0-beta.28

LoginScreen.js

```js
const facebookLogin = () => {

  return LoginManager
.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
.then((result) => {

  if (!result.isCancelled) {
    console.log(`Login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`)
    // get the access token
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
  }
})
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    // create a new firebase credential with the token
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)
    // login with credential
    return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
  }
})
.then((currentUser) => {
  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
    return this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(`Login fail with error: ${error}`)
})
}
```

After (currentUser), I added following that.
`this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');`

But that doesn't work!
I have already set up Router, and that did work at out of Auth Component.

I checked at console.log and that shows me:

> Login fail with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined"

So I tried to move `const { navigation } = this.props;` from Auth Component to other SigninScreen Component. But I can't see successful login.

Thanks for your answer. And I have defined already in Parent component.

I defined navigation here.

```js
class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={facebookLogin}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Facebook</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `navigation` object is undefined. Check the parent component to see if `navigation` is defined before it is passed as props to this component

It could also be due to the way javascript handles the `this` keyword. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176279/8955048) You could try binding the navigate method to the Class by adding

`this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate.bind(this)` inside the constructor,

and change

```
.then((currentUser) => {
  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
    return this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }
```

to

```
.then((currentUser) => {
  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
    return this.navigate('Main');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I have defined already in Parent component.

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

Comment: It could be that the "this" you are reffering to within `.then((currentUser) => {
  if (currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
    return this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }
})` refers to the "this" inside the method scope. I suggest reading this article. [https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: I'm glad it does! Oh and by the way, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!