# Puppeteer: log HTML DOM object in evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

When I run a puppeteer script , if I want to do a log inside the page.evaluate I can use a code like bellow

```
page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
```

Unfortunately , it does not work if I want to log an object:

For example the code below does not log properly a js obj:

```
page.on("console", log => {
   console[log._type](log.text());
});

await pageBis.evaluate(() => {
   let selector = `select.form1 option[value="optionToSelect"]`;
   let optionObj = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];
   console.log(`optionObj : ${JSON.stringify(optionObj)}`);
});
```

It displays :

> optionObj : {}

Do you know how to handle it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

If you open `about:blank` on your default browser and run the following,

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('body')))
```

and it will return `{}`, because it's trying to convert a HTML element to a string which is not possible.

## Solution: [domjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domjson)

There are lots of ways to do this. You can use such library from within the browser with `addScriptTag` and console out or use as you wish.

**Usage:**

```
// add the script to the window like <script src="...">
await page.addScriptTag({url:"https://www.unpkg.com/domjson"})

// run the code inside browser, we have domJSON available on window now
await page.evaluate(()=>{

  // use it
  const bodyJson = domJSON.toJSON(document.querySelector('body'));

  // log it
  console.log(JSON.stringify(bodyJson, true, 2))
})
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "meta": {
    "href": "about:blank",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "clock": 1,
    "date": "2018-10-22T15:08:03.973Z",
    "dimensions": {
      "inner": {
        "x": 1920,
        "y": 476
      },
      "outer": {
        "x": 1920,
        "y": 993
      }
    },
...
```

`domjson` was last published on npm 4 years ago, but still works to satisfy the needs of this question and does not probably pose any great security issues, also have no external dependencies. Their github page is last updated 20 days ago with several fixes.

**Note:**

- There are several other modules to deal with dom like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) etc.
- Whatever you do inside `.evaluate`, it runs in the **browser context**.
- Whatever you do outside it will run in the **nodeJS context**. So you will have to treat them differently. Learn more about context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328519/different-in-scope-and-context-in-this-javascript-code).
- DOM means **HTML DOM (Document Object Model)**, it is (only) available inside the browser, so it's best to use it there if possible.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds great but it seems to be difficult to use:  
if I install it via npm it triggers an error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property "href' of undefined"
If I try your code directly, it gives me the error"
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: domjson is not defined"
if I write await pageBis.evaluate((domjson) => {
...
 }, domjson);
it's going to give me error.
"Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: domjson.toJSON is not a function"

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly for me on example.com. http://i.imgur.com/Ss1LlWF.png, maybe a cors issue?

Comment: please do you know why domJSON  works inside evaluate  in spite of  if I try to use domJSON outside evaluate it triggers an error "domJSON is not defined" ?

Comment: Whatever you do inside .evaluate, it runs in the browser. Whatever you do outside it will run in the nodeJS. So you will have to treat them differently. Also the dom is (only) available inside the browser, so it's best to use it there if possible.