# forEach problem: lineTo is not defined at CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript

I tried using a forEach loop on an array of points and a canvas drawing context.
This is a simplified sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<<script>
// assume this is going to be some code independent of the calling web page
function showPoints(context,data) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0,0); 
  context.lineTo(0,  data[0]);  // OK
  data.forEach(function(pt,i){
      lineTo(10*i, pt);     // Error
      lineTo(10*(i+1), pt);  
  },context); // to be made available to the forEach callback
  context.stroke();
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas">
<script>
  const data = [10,20,25,30,25];
  const c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   
  showPoints(ctx, data);
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

This fails with **ReferenceError: lineTo is not defined at CanvasRenderingContext2D**

Sure, ctx.lineTo is defined, used before, and still visible directly above the forEach line.

Passing ctx as a *this* parameter also seems ok, in my understanding of the error message.

A regular named function did not make a difference.

Any hints on what I'm doing/understanding wrong, please? (Javascript is not my native language)
Sure I could replace the forEach construct, or use the global context constant, but I want to learn its usage.

Comment: `this.lineTo(..)` is not equivalent to just `lineTo(..)`.

Comment: you are calling `lineTo`, which is a function that doesn't exist. Why not just call `ctx.lineTo` again?

Comment: you are calling `lineTo` by mistake as a function in `scope` please note `ctx.lineTo`

Comment: >`Why not just call ctx.lineTo again?` ctx is available to the forEach callback only because it's a global variable. I tried to use the optional *this* parameter of the forEach construct.

Comment: I was thinking of explaining this myself but this answer does a better job then I ever could https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328520/1552587

Comment: Actually, after going though that answer more throughly, it doesn't seem that revealing. The main problem is the difference between scope and context in JavaScript.

Comment: `context.lineTo`, then.

Comment: If you really wish, there is a legacy `with` statement. But that's really not recommended. Better you adopt JS style from the get go: `context` is available in your forEach scope.

Comment: Thanks, @Ry~ ! I'm still not really used to the benefits of inner (anonymous) functions, having the full variables scope of the outer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Titus mentioned in his comment already, to use a method context (*this*) you  can pass it to the forEach callback, but you have to use it there by explicitly mentioning this.

```
function showPoints(context,data) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0,0); 
  data.forEach(function(pt,i){
      this.lineTo(10*i, pt);    
      this.lineTo(10*(i+1), pt);  
  },context); // to be made available to the forEach callback
  context.stroke();
}
```

Additionally: due to the nested function definition, passing `context` as *this* is not necessary here, as `context` is directly accessible by the anonymous inner function.

Thanks to all helping me dig deeper into JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the comments under your post have mentioned, there is no `lineTo()` available to be called. However, `ctx.lineTo()` does exist, and would not cause an error.

Comment: Coming from C++ my idea was,  this.lineTo() and lineTo() were equivalent. And the message `lineTo is not defined at CanvasRenderingContext2D` was misleading me.
ctx.lineTo refers to a global variable, which is suboptimal if you consider the sample function being rather independent from the calling script.